# zsh run-help-git error: shift count must be <= $#

Tags: macos, git, zsh

I've enabled `run-help` in my `.zshrc` file as recommended at the [ArchLinux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Zsh#Help_command):

```bsh
unalias run-help
autoload -Uz run-help
alias help=run-help
```

This works fine for most commands and builtins e.g. `help cd`, however whenever I activate any of the assistant functions `run-help-git` or `run-help-sudo` etc., I get the following error:

```bsh
$ autoload -Uz run-help-git
$ help git blame
git is /usr/local/bin/git
run-help:shift:107: shift count must be <= $#
```

I'm running `zsh 5.7.1` from Homebrew on macOS 10.14.4. As far as I can tell there's nothing interfering with this in my [config files](https://github.com/starbase527/dotfiles). I use the exact same dotfiles on a Raspberry Pi running Arch, and I don't encounter this problem there.

I haven't found anybody else encountering this problem online, does anybody have any ideas how to start debugging this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same problem. Took some time to figure it out.

All you have to do is make sure you got a ' ' (space) at the end of the alias (otherwise it won't interpret stuff after it as parameters). Alternatively just disable the alias. (if that alone doesn't work you have to navigate to /usr/share/zsh/functions/Misc and set execute permissions on the run-help-* files but i don't think that's even necessary)

So the config should then look something like this:

```
unalias run-help
autoload -Uz run-help
alias help='run-help '
```

Comment: Hmm, neither changing the alias nor setting the execute permissions fixed the problem for me. Also, if something like that was the problem, why doesn't it occur on my Arch system?

Comment: Alright, just found something else to try. what happens if you remove the -Uz from the autoload? Found a comment saying -U supresses alias expansion so that might interfere with it.  See also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/214306

Comment: No, that makes no difference too. :(

Comment: Does anyone know anything about this issue? I have the same issue on macOS Catalina and I am using `zsh 5.8`. I have tried many things including rearranging the order of the commands, dropping some of the `autoload` flags, and not using the alias but none of these options seem to work. Interestingly, typing the commands directly into the command line works but putting them in the `.zshrc` does not.